# Is using session variables more efficient than multiple reads of an ini file

Tags: php

I have an application that reads from an INI file using the excellent parse_ini_file then stores those values in session variables for use in other pages.  If a value does not exist in a session variable then it is retrieved from the ini file.

I am now having second thoughts about the efficiency of this.  As I understand it a session id is stored in a cookie on the client which when retrieved is used to extract a user file from the server.  This seems like a lot more work than just constantly reading an ini file into memory (the ini file is pretty small).  Also there are all the potential pitfalls with cookies such as them being unavailable or interfered with.

Should I save the coding complexity and just keep calling parse_ini_file for each page that need values from the ini file?

Very much related, but another solution may be available, I have an application that makes multiple JSON calls to PHP code to perform database updates in response to user actions (on a Google map).  Each call requires a database connection to be made, which seems very inefficient.  I tried passing the database connection resource through the JSON call not expecting this to work (it didn't) and sending the dsn, username and password would have security implications and a database connection would still have to be made.  Am I stuck with having to make a database connection each time my php update scripts are called?

Comment: This is where debugging and profiling come in handy. Just try the different methods and do some profiling in the meanwhile. That should give you the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a php developer, but here's my advice:

1. Keep using the session Id, it's more efficient than file I/O. Almost everything is. It's also wiser in case the ini file changes at some point and you end up with inconsistent data due to that. Or imagine if the ini file is on a slower nfs or something.
2. Use a Connection Pool. I don't know what the options for this are in php, but you will need a new connection for each request and the pool can handle the intricacies of fetching one, closing it, limiting things, etc.